# Use Field values in $lookup function in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, variables, mongoose, aggregation-framework, lookup

Right now I am facing an issue where I want to join collections in Mongo based on a variable because the data is stored in a different collection.

My dataset would look like

```
{
    _id:5e424331134cea013014ea9e0,
    process:"Process1",
    event:"Event1",
    collection:"Collection1",
    Date:"2020-02-11",
},
{
    _id:5e424135151cea32114ea9e0,
    process:"Process2",
    event:"Event2",
    collection:"Collection2",
    Date:"2020-02-11",
}
```

The collection where I need the data from is maintained in the value of the field `$collection`.

The collections are looking like this:

**Collection1:**

```
{
    _id:5e63636636cea32114ea9e0,
    item:81740147,
    value:2,
    Date:"2020-02-11",
}
```

**Collection2:**

```
{
    _id:5e63636636cea32114ea9e0,
    user:testuser,
    age:3,
    Date:"2020-02-11",
}
```

What I want to achieve in the aggregation pipiline is to join my documents based on the collection name.

What I already tried:

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: '$collection',
        localField: 'Date',
        foreignField: 'Date',
        as: 'join'
    }
}
```

This did not work for me.
Maybe you have a different idea.

Please keep in mind that I only can use the aggregation framework to solve the problem and not the cli of the mongodb.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm in the same predicament

Answer (score 0):

Change it to something like this

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'collectionname', // the name you specified when creating your model
        localField: 'Date',
        foreignField: 'Date',
        as: 'join'
    }
}
```

It has to be same as what you created your model with, it won't work otherwise

If your collection name is dynamic,

You can always use variable instead there,

like you can do something like this

```
var coll_name = 'collectionname';

{
    $lookup: {
        from: coll_name,
        localField: 'Date',
        foreignField: 'Date',
        as: 'join'
    }
}
```

Now, you can pass this dynamic collection name from anywhere to your function / api

Comment: I actually want to avoid typing in the collection itself like from: 'Collection 1' because the collection names in my data set will update from time to time which means every time it is updated I also have to update my aggregation.

Comment: check out this updated answer, you can pass dynamic variable in collection nam, it totally works like this