# Use field value as from parameter in lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to know if there is a way to use as "from" parameter of a lookup operation the value of a field of another collection.

This is an example of document:

```
{
  "name": "TEST ONE",
  "refId": "12345",
  "refCollection": "unitsOnBoard"
}
```

I would like to use the value of the field "refCollection" in the from parameter in a lookup operation, something like this:

```
{
   "from": "$refCollection",
   "localField": "refId",
   "foreignField" "_id",
   "as": "units"
}
```

But it does not work. Do you have any suggestions? Or perhaps is it something that cannot be done at all?

I think this post may be considered a duplicate of [Use Field values in $lookup function in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60165177/use-field-values-in-lookup-function-in-mongodb), but this last one did not receive a pertinent answer to the question.

Comment: As far as I know, No, you can't do that in a MongoDB query. The only way I could think is to make it in 2 steps on your code. First get your document with the collection and set that to a variable, and  then you make you second query with the `from` alredy set.

Comment: Ok, I supposed it was not supported, even if it would be very useful in some situation. I'll follow your suggestion and do two separated pipeline.